# Cypher: Travel in several crossed chained list

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph with users.
In this graph their are also activities (nodes). Each user have a chained list of its activities :

```
(user)-[:NEXT_ACTIVITY*]->(activities)
```

But there is one tricky part : an activity can be owned by 2 users. So I set a property "idUser" in my NEXT_ACTIVITY relation, with the ID of the user. This is how I can find all activities for 1 user.

```
START user=node:users('name:JohnDoe')
MATCH (user)-[rel:NEXT_ACTIVITY*]->(activities)
WHERE ALL (r in rel WHERE r.idUser = id(user))
```

My problem is that I don't know how to get activities for several users with this system. How can I travel chained list of several users, and being sure that all **NEXT_ACTIVITY** the graph travel belongs to these users ?

The use case : I want to get activities of a user and its friends.

Regards,
Raphaël

Ps: the reason why an activity can be owned by 2 users is that if **A** publish on **B**'s wall, it's an activity for A and B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first get all friends of the user(say name='u1'), that includes the user as well since the length of the relationship is 0..1, and then for each of them, get all activities.

```
Match u:User-[:FRIEND*0..1]->friend:User
Where u.name = 'u1'
With friend 
Match friend-[rel:NEXT_ACTIVITY*]->activity
Where all(r in rel where r.idUser = id(friend))
Return friend.name, collect(activity.name)
```

if you just need all activities regardless of users, then "Return distinct activity.name"

Comment: Hello, Thank you it works :) That was simple, I don't know why i didn't tried that first. Many thanks, regards :)

Comment: @Lisa I am trying your query exactly the same way. But unable to fetch the results. Can some one help me in this ?                                               "Match (u:Student)-[:FRIEND*0..1]->(friend:Student)
Where u.fullName = 'Sateesh Havannavar'
With friend 
Match (friend)-[rel:TIMELINE*]->(activity)
Where all(r in rel where r.idUser = id(friend))
Return friend.me.fullName"