# How to get only friends of friends in Neo4j using Cypher

Tags: node.js, database, neo4j, nosql, cypher

Hello I would like to make a social network. Currently I am trying to display 'friends of friends' so that I can recommend friends to the user. I am implementing the Neo4j queries in a Node.js server. The problem is that I get a syntax error with my current Cypher syntax. I hope someone can take a look at the query and tell me what's wrong.

Cypher syntax:

```
MATCH (n:User{mongoId: {idNeo}}) 
MATCH n-[:FRIENDS_WITH*2]-m 
WHERE NOT n-[:FRIENDS_WITH]-m 
RETURN m
```

Entire route:

```
routes.get('/users/friendsoffriends/:id', function(req, res) {
  //res.contentType('application/json');
  var ids = [];
  const id = req.param('id');

  session
    .run("MATCH (n:User{mongoId: {idNeo}}) MATCH n-[:FRIENDS_WITH*2]-m WHERE NOT n-[:FRIENDS_WITH]-m RETURN m", {idNeo: id})
    .then(function(result) {
      result.records.forEach(function(record){
        ids.push(record._fields[0].properties.mongoUserId);
      });
      console.log(ids);
      return ids;
    })
    .then((ids)=>{
      User.find({_id: { $in: ids}})
          .then((blogPost) => {
          res.status(200).json(blogPost);
        })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(400).json(error);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Cypher query is missing parens around the nodes in your graph pattern. Try this:

```
MATCH (n:User{mongoId: {idNeo}}) 
MATCH  (n)-[:FRIENDS_WITH*2]-(m) 
WHERE NOT (n)-[:FRIENDS_WITH]-(m) 
RETURN m
```

Comment: Thanks, a stupid mistake. Do you happen to know how I can exclude n being in the result? If I now want to know person A's friends of friends, person A himself shows up too.

Comment: Do you have multiple :FRIENDS_WITH relationships between the same two nodes? That's the only way I know of for a *2 expansion to return to the starting node. Seems like it could be a modeling issue? Otherwise, if this is correct for your graph, add `AND n <> m` to your WHERE clause.

Comment: Refering to the below link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19032147/cypher-travel-in-several-crossed-chained-list
I tried running below query, but no luck for me, can someone help me
Match u:Student-[:FRIEND*0..1]->friend:Student
Where u.id = 84
With friend 
Match friend-[rel:TIMELINE*]->activity
Where all(r in rel where r.idUser = id(friend))
Return friend.me.fullName